# I want to generate android apk and I have this error in Ionic 4

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, cordova-plugins, ionic4

```
d:\Projets-et-Formations\IONIC\GApp>ionic cordova build android
> cordova platform add android --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^8.0.0
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: io.ionic.starter
        Name: Illimi_na_kowa
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-28
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Android project created with cordova-android@8.1.0
Installing "cordova-plugin-app-preferences" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-app-preferences': CordovaError: Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "path" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.        
    at Context.requireCordovaModule (C:\Users\ss\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\Context.js:57:15)
    at module.exports (d:\Projets-et-Formations\IONIC\GApp\plugins\cordova-plugin-app-preferences\bin\before_plugin_install.js:6:14)
    at runScriptViaModuleLoader (C:\Users\ss\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:181:32)
    at runScript (C:\Users\ss\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:157:16)
    at C:\Users\ss\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:125:20   
Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "path" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova platform add android --save exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: what have you try so far?. Looking at the error, it seems to me you have a problem with a plugin that is build with a newest version of cordova. Check again the error. There are several other post with similar problems in SO, most of them were solve it by re installing cordova or the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Cordova version 9 is not compatible with the plugin `cordova-plugin-app-preferences`. There's an open [issue](https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences/issues/147) at the plugin's GitHub.

You have couple options:

1. Downgrade your Cordova version
2. Fork the plugin and fix the problem by replacing all occurrences like `context.requireCordovaModule('path')` to `require('path')` by your own. It's not that difficult, here's an example of similar change for another [plugin](https://github.com/scor4er/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/commit/df19086e6ae24977ceee85d1a07b4466f519e3e9). But there might be other issues you might need to fix, of course.